# Selenium ChromeDriver silently fails to click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For some reason, the Selenium "click" command no longer works on my laptop. It doesn't throw an 'Element is not clickable' error or anything, it acts like it succeeded but no click actually happens.

I set up a very simple example to debug: a plain HTML page with a `<form method="post" action="/whatever">` containing a single button with `type='submit'`.

Looking at Selenium logs, it appears to be sending the POST command to `/click` without an issue. Looking at the `chromedriver` logs, it seems to be happily clicking:

```
[14.199][INFO]: COMMAND Click {
   "button": 0
}
...
[14.202][INFO]: RESPONSE Click
```

To add to the mystery, I tried adding a CSS class `my-button:hover { background-color: red }`. When I try doing Selenium's `moveToCenter` command on the button, the red hover color does not appear. (The hover works properly on other test machines.)

So, it seems mouse cursor related things aren't working in general. Other Selenium functionality seems okay--triggering the "submit" action on the button works, for example.

FWIW, this happened in the last week or so. Nothing has changed to my knowledge on my laptop (like Chrome updates, etc.) The Selenium tests still work fine on other machines, like my Jenkins server.

Comment: So what is your Question? Can you show us your work please? Thanks

Comment: Need more information, can you paste DOM and code ?

Comment: The question is, how could I debug this further?

The DOM is as I said, just a `<form>` input with a single button -- nothing tricky going on there. The code is probably not super helpful since I'm using the Haskell language bindings. It's very simple, just the Haskell version of "let x = findElement "my-button"; moveToCenter x; click x" with some sleeps in between. I can see from the Selenium/ChromeDriver logs that the correct commands are being sent into Selenium.

Comment: (I've also tried clicking on other things like `<a href="#" onclick="alert('hi')">Click me</a>`, which also doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out this problem only happens when the `--user-data-dir` option is provided to ChromeDriver. I was using the same directory every time, and evidently this folder eventually got into a weird state, which caused this problem. Blowing away the user data dir at the beginning of the test run seems to fix the problem.